# Similar functions produce different outputs

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, namespaces

I am trying to compile the files below. The `PosLin.cpp` contains the `SurTriAuto` and `getSphere` functions below. Although they are similar, I am not getting the same results. Is it because the "namespace TPiecesNS" causes them to be different?

I have a `tpieces.h` file

```
namespace TPiecesNS
{
  class TPieces
  {
  public:
    TPieces();
    //other stuff
  }
}
```

`tpieces.cpp` has:

```
void TPieces::addPoint(Vertex* point)
{
    Vertex* p = new Vertex();
    p->Point[0] = point->Point[0]; //similar for Point[1],[2]
    p->Normal[0] = point->Normal[0]; //same for 1,2
    m_Vertices.push_back(p);
}
```

`geopar.h` file has

```
#include "tpieces.h"
#include "Geo/Geo.h"

class Geo;

namespace TPiecesNS
{
   class GeoPar;
   {
    public:
          GeoPar();
          TPieces* getSphere(Geo* geo);
          TPieces* getSphere(Geo* geo, int permu);
    private:
      TPieces* SurTriAuto(TPieces* boundary, Geo* geo,int permu);

   }
}
```

`geopar.cpp` file has

```
#include "tpieces/geo.h"
#include "tpieces.h"
#include "Geo/Geo.h"

using namespace TPiecesNS;

TPieces* GeoPar::getSphere(Geo* geo) {
    return getSphere(geo, 0);
}

TPieces* GeoPar::getSphere(Geo* geo, int permu)
{
TPieces* boundary = new Sphere();
return SurTriAuto(boundary,geo,permu);
}

TPieces* GeoPar::SurTriAuto(TPieces* boundary, Geo* geo, int permu)
{
  double maxx, maxy, maxz, minx, miny, minz;
  double        x,y,z,f,nx,ny,nz;
  int number = 6;

  ofstream file;
  file.open("output.txt");

  boundary->numbpts = geo->m_NumTriVerts;
  boundary->numbtris = geo->m_NumTris; 
  file<<"NumVertices "<<boundary->numbpts<<endl;
  file<<"NumTrianlges "<<boundary->numbtris<<endl;

  for (i = 0 ; i < boundary->numbpts; i++)
  {
    x = geometry->m_TriVerts[i*3+0];
    //also equalities for y,z, but I don't want to type here in order to save space
    nx = geometry->m_TriVertNormals[i*3+0];
        //ny, nz also
    if (x < minx) minx = x;
        //comparisons for y,z also and comparing to maxx, maxy, maxz

    Vertex* point = new Vertex();
        point->Point[0] = x;
        point->Point[1] = y;
        point->Point[2] = z;

    point->Normal[0] = nx; //also assignments for ny, nz
    file<<"xyz normals: "<<point->Point[0]<<endl;
    //I also printed out  y,z,nx,ny,nz
        boundary->addPoint(point);
  }

      for (i = 0 ; i < boundary->numbtris; i++)
 {
    ii = geo->m_Tris[i*3+0]; //assignments for jj, kk also
        if (ii < jj && jj < kk)    { i1 = ii; i2 = jj;  i3 = kk; }
       //similar comparisons for jj and kk also here, but I want to save space
        //...
        if (kk < ii && ii < jj)    { i1 = kk; i2 = ii;  i3 = jj; }  // result in i1 <= i2 <= i3

       Face* facet = new Face();
       facet->Index[0] = i1; //i2, i3 are also assigned
      facet->IndexInR[0] = ii; //jj, kk also

      boundary->addFacet(facet);
    }   /* end facet (i) loop */

 for (i = 0 ; i <boundary->numbtris; i++)
 {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        int index = boundary->m_Faces[i]->Index[j];
        for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            file<<boundary->m_Faces[i]->Normal[k]<<" "<<boundary->m_Vertices[index]->Normal[k]<<endl;
            boundary->m_Faces[i]->Normal[k] += boundary->m_Vertices[index]->Normal[k];   
            //ERROR IS  HERE
            file<<boundary->m_Faces[i]->Normal[k]<<endl;
        }
    }
 }  

return boundary;
```

}

and `PosLin.h` has

```
#include "TPieces/tpieces.h"
#include "TPieces/geoPar.h"
#include "Geo/Geo.h"

struct PosRotAndQ {

  TPiecesNS::TPieces* boundary;
};

class PS{
public: 

  PosExCode computation(Geo* geo, POpinion* opinion, PositionRotation* matterboundary)

  PositionRotation* matterboundary;

}
```

and `PosLin.cpp` has

```
#include "tpieces/tpieces.h"
#include "Geo/Geo.h"

PosExCode PS::computation(Geo* geo, POpinion* opinion, PositionRotation* matterboundary)

{
    TPiecesNS::GeoPar* perform = new TPiecesNS::GeoPar();
    TPiecesNS::TPieces* boundary = new TPiecesNS::Sphere();
    boundary->sphere = perform->SurTriAuto(boundary, geo,0);//if I comment this line out and the line below and un-comment the 2 getSphere lines below, they do not produce the same output
    boundary->sphereDark[0] = perform->SurTriAuto(boundary, geo,0); \
    //boundary->sphere = perform->getSphere(geo,0);
    //boundary->sphereDark[0] = perform->getSphere(geo,0);
}
```

I noticed that the getSphere and SurTriAuto get different outputs, specifically at the line `surface->m_Faces[i]->Normal[k] +=
                                surface->m_Vertices[index]->Normal[k];`

In the outputted textfile, before the `+=` operation takes place, the values `surface->m_Faces[i]->Normal[k]` and `surface->m_Vertices[index]->Normal[k]` and are not the same for getSphere and SurTriAuto, even though all the other values (such as the x,y,z,index values) are the same.

I suspect this is because one of the `boundary` pointers loses values in `TPieces* boundary = new Sphere();` in getSphere in GeoPar.cpp and/or `TPiecesNS::TPieces* boundary = new TPiecesNS::Sphere();` in PosLin.cpp

Comment: There is much code in your post but it's not clear how one would see the problem. Try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just edited the OP

Comment: Just wondering the lines in question, commenting and uncommenting, the functions are different, different output would be expected. You have overloaded the the constructor (which is fine.) But the one with one starting with one parameter is going to do something else with the two parameter. The code within those functions are different.

Comment: why though? If I comment out `SurTriAuto` and use `getSphere` instead, `getSphere` calls `SurTriAuto`, so I don't understand how they produce a different output

Comment: Updated my post, read and reply.

Comment: So you're saying `perform->getSphere(geo, 0)` should produce a different output than `perform->getSphere(geo)`? why exactly? so I should just get rid of the constructor with just one parameter, that is `TPieces* GeoPar::getSphere(Geo* geo) `?

Answer (score 0):

In one case you have both functions using the same `boundary` object. In the other case each function uses a fresh `boundary` object.

You haven't shown what the `TPieces` class does, but I assume that `addPoint` and `addFacet` change the contents of the `TPieces` class, such that when you write the `faces` to the file in the second call, you end up getting the `faces` that were saved in the first call.

To make the two cases work the same, try using a different `boundary` object in the second call. Something like this:

```
TPiecesNS::GeoPar* perform = new TPiecesNS::GeoPar();
TPiecesNS::TPieces* boundary = new TPiecesNS::Sphere();
boundary->sphere = perform->SurTriAuto(boundary, geo,0);//if I comment this line out and the line below and un-comment the 2 getSphere lines below, they do not produce the same output
TPiecesNS::TPieces* boundary2 = new TPiecesNS::Sphere();
boundary->sphereDark[0] = perform->SurTriAuto(boundary2, geo,0);
//boundary->sphere = perform->getSphere(geo,0);
//boundary->sphereDark[0] = perform->getSphere(geo,0);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. The two cases now produce similar outputs. I have another unrelated question though. In my output `boundary->m_Vertices[index]->Normal[k]`, it is displaying 0 for the first line (when i=j=k=index=0). This doesn't make sense because `nx = geo->m_TriVertNormals[i*3+0];` and then `point->Normal[0] = nx` assigned a non-zero value for `point->Normal[0] `. I also just edited the OP to include the relevant code for TPieces.cpp and the `addPoint` function

Comment: In your code, you have `nx = geometry->m_TriVertNormals[i*3+0];` I am not sure where `geometry` comes from. Shouldn't it be `geo`? The best suggestion I can give is to use a debugger to step through the code and make sure `nx` is the right value when it is added, and ensure that the addPoint function adds it properly.

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be `geo`. I made a typo. What debugger can I use? I already tried valgrind and gdc but neither detected any problems

Comment: Which debugger depends on your environment. If you are on Linux (guessing from the valgrind reference), you can use gdb as a command line debugger. If you are using an IDE, then it probably has a debugger built in. Note that the debugger won't detect problems for you, you will need to set breakpoints at the various lines in your code and inspect variables when your program gets to those breakpoints.